Vertical centering of cells in a spreadtab environment
I'm trying to correctly align vertically all the cells in the following table created with the spreadtab environment that I need because I need to do both calculations and cross referencing with images (not included). In particular all the cells containing date and the amounts should be correctly aligned  both horizontally and vertically. How should this be achieved?
This is what I have obtained (vertical centering not achieved).
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-space-text-post={\,\euro}, 
         table-align-text-post=false}
\usepackage{makecell, numprint}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{varioref}
 \npdecimalsign{,}
\title{Spreadsheet}
\author{}
\date{}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\STautoround*{2}
\begin{document}
\chapter{CH1}
\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{6cm}|N{4}{2}|N{4}{2}|N{4}{2}|c|}}
\hline
     @Date & @Title1 &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\makecell{@ Bla1\\ (\euro)}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\makecell{@Bla2 \\ (\euro)}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\makecell{@Bla3\\ (\euro)}}&@Note\\
     \hline
     @08/07/2024 & @A very very very long description of any kind  & 12.10&0&0&@Pag.23 \\
\hline
  @19/07/2024 & @Another very long description to be inserted here  & 0&0&1000.00&@---\\
\hline
      & \hfill@Total:& sum(c2:c3) &sum(d2:d3) &sum(e2:e3) &\\
     \hline
          & \hfill@Difference:& & & & d4-c4 \\
     \hline
\end{spreadtab}\\
\end{center}
\end{document}


